# failed to start session in Ubuntu trusty tahr

Tags: 14.04

Accidentally purged *glib2.0* and during the purge when I started to notice things like uninstalling software center and the likes, I did a force shutdown.

Now during my Ubuntu login I get *failed to start session* message.

I have tried to install Ubuntu-desktop from the terminal (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) but nothing is working.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than *"nothing is working"* - what **exactly** did you try, and what happened?

Comment: As it turns out, i did not have my wifi on (i know!) during the install ubuntu-desktop command. I was panicking when I posted it and hence the vagueness.

Comment: Admitting an embarrassment is worthy of respect - it means you care for the time and effort of others.

Answer (score 0):

Seems from your descriptions that did TWO very unwise things:

- You didn't reading the list before accepting the uninstall.
- You panicked and depowered your system during package operations.

Those errors compound each other. Either can be recovered from fairly easily, but together is much harder.

If you accidentally uninstall a critical system package, it's usually better to let the package action finish, then simply restore the packages using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or similar. Never interrupt apt while it is working unless you are an expert.

Your **easiest** solution is to backup your data using a LiveUSB and then reinstall.

If you want to **fix the damage**, that may be a long road...or it may not. Either way, the AskUbuntu format is ill-suited to the one-on-one support you will need, and the answers to you problem are unlikely to help anybody  else. Jump over to http://ubuntuforums.org and open a thread there for one-on-one tutoring on how to diagnose the problems and fix them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. as it turns out, I did not turn my wi-fi on(it pains me more to write it out than the pain you have to endure by reading it, probably) during the install ubuntu-desktop command.